# Export HTMLtable to CSV in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron, export-to-csv

I am making an electron app (using Node Js) where I need to export HTML table data to a .csv file.
I followed [this](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/) tutorial to implement this.
The function I used is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

        // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
        if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
                type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
            });

            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
            // HTML5 Blob        
            var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8' });
            var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            $(this).attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href': csvUrl
            });
        } else {
            // Data URI
            var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

            $(this).attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
            });
        }
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        var args = [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv'];

        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

        // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

For the output csv file, I have given a default name "export.csv".

The problem that I am facing is as follows.

When I run this electron app in Windows (I have used [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) to package it, Ubuntu being my host computer),

In the Windows dialog box that appears asking me where to save the document
[image]

If I don't change the default name "export.csv" present in the "File name" field, I get a valid export.csv file as the output.
A screenshot is attached below for reference

[image]

But If I change the name present in the "File name" field to a different name (ex : temp), I don't get a .csv file . Instead I get a file as shown in the image below.

[image]

Can someone please tell me how can I get a valid .csv file as my output file even if the user changes the output "File Name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the code you're using to display the Windows dialog box, but I think the simplest thing to do is to make it default to a `.csv` extension.

You can do this by setting the `filters` in your call to `showSaveDialog`.

For example:

```
var filename = dialog.showSaveDialog({
  filters: [
    { name: 'CSV files', extensions: ['csv'] }
  ]
});
```

That way, when the user enters their own filename, the result will default to a `.csv` extension.

Comment: I have not written any code for the Windows Dialog Box.
Electron does it on it's own.
function exportTableToCSV() is called when user clicks the export button which exports the HTML table to CSV

Comment: In that case, I'd probably change the code to show a dialog box, then save the file manually using [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback). That way you're in full control of the file saving. Currently you're relying on Chromium's general file saving behaviour, so you've got no control over filenames.